# How can HierarchyViewer tool of android studio know the properties of views of android screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I want to know how hierarchyViewer tool works in android. As all the android app runs in different processes, how can it know the layout of views. Who pushes the views and its properties to hierarchyViewer.

Which service of android push data to HierarchyViewer tool.
Can someone please explain me this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets first look at how adb is organized. It has 3 main components as described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) -

1. **client** - A clients running on the machine being used for the development. Client is invoked from shell by issuing a adb command. Hierarchy viewer also creates adb client.
2. **server** - A server which runs as a background process on your development machine.It communicates the commands issued from the adb client to the adbd(adb daemon).
3. **adbd** - Adb daemon runs as a background process on each emulator or device. adb daemon is responsible for the communication of the data from the emulator or device to the adb server. adb daemon communicates to various services running on the device via Binder which is an **IPC** like mechanism.

For example when we issue a command like `adb install example.apk` on shell.
It first invokes adb client on the machine and tells it wants to install example.apk.
Then server then sends the apk along with the command to the the adb daemon running on the device. The communication is done done by adb bridge communicating via TCP connection generally running at port 5554. Then adb daemon calls the **System server** to carry out the command.

Now lets have a look at the android device side of the story -

On every android device there is a server called as a **System Server**. You can find the status of this by issuing the command `adb shell ps | grep system_server`. The System server is responsible for management of services. Some services run by the System Server are

- Device Policy
- Audio Service
- Power Manager
- Package Manager
- Content Providers
- **Window Manager**
- Activity Manager
  and many more....

The Window Manager has information like - Main Thread, Window manipulation, orientation, layering, input event management, focus etc. The information on your views is already available with the Windows Manager.

So now putting everything together the final flow for the hierarchy viewer is -

1. Hierarchy viewer creates adb client asking the information on viewswhen issued a command like `REMOTE_COMMAND_CAPTURE_LAYERS` or `COMMAND_WINDOW_MANAGER_LIST`.
2. The request reaches adb server which forwards it to the **adbd** on device running the application.
3. adbd forwards the request to the System Server who identifies the service to which the request has to be forwarded. Which in this case is **Window Manger**.
4. Window Manger then asks **View Manager** which is responsible for the managing of the thread pool for the main UI thread of application.
5. View Manager returns this information to the Window Manager.
6. Window Manager sends data back to adbd.
7. Adbd communicates it back to adb server.
8. adb server gives data back to hierarchy viewer.

   Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the info... this means that "Window Manager" has access to all the views of the current window.. then why does hierarchyViewer only shows some properties only but not all. For example if the View is TextView..then why doesn't hierarchyViewer also shows the TextColor, backgroundColor, padding, etc...but it only shows text, clickable, enables, etc...

Comment: See the official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/hierarchy-viewer/index.html), It has all the available properties for the view. Look at point 15 and 16, it will be able to provide you will all the details of the view.

Comment: I can only run hierarchy for my own app using [ViewServer](https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer). Can I run hierarchyViewer if debug mode is ON for other apps?

Comment: thanks for the above..just want to make sure I am not going in wrong direction

Comment: I think when hierarchy viewer was showcased, they showed how they can improve performance of apps  which were not their own. So I think that it can be done. But I believe they have intentionally removed the ability to view other apps so as not that people will not copy other's apps.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question, i don't have the good answer but my first reaction i tired to see the **logcat** when i start **HierarchyViewer** and this is what i found very interesting (half road):

```
1873-21873/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
01-16 20:10:37.246 21873-21873/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
01-16 20:10:37.283 21873-21873/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/local/tmp/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-16 20:10:37.341 21873-21873/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
01-16 20:10:37.361 21873-21873/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher
01-16 20:10:38.551 21873-21873/? I/AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper: Skipping invisible child: android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@80031f7d; boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 1412, 1692); boundsInScreen: Rect(0, 322 - -13, 2014); packageName: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox; className: android.view.ViewGroup; text: null; error: null; maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: null; viewIdResName: null; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: false; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: true; longClickable: true; contextClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false; scrollable: false; actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLICK - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_LONG_CLICK - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_UNKNOWN - null]
01-16 20:10:38.582 21873-21873/? I/AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper: Skipping invisible child: android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@80031bbc; boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 324, 380); boundsInScreen: Rect(312, 1676 - 636, 2014); packageName: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox; className: android.view.View; text: null; error: null; maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: null; viewIdResName: null; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: false; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: false; longClickable: false; contextClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false; scrollable: false; actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_UNKNOWN - null]
01-16 20:10:38.583 21873-21873/? I/AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper: Skipping invisible child: android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@8003c4a9; boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 1412, 1692); boundsInScreen: Rect(1454, 322 - 1440, 2014); packageName: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox; className: android.view.ViewGroup; text: null; error: null; maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: null; viewIdResName: null; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: false; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: true; longClickable: true; contextClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false; scrollable: false; actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLICK - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_LONG_CLICK - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_UNKNOWN - null]
01-16 20:10:38.584 21873-21873/? I/AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper: Skipping invisible child: android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@80033603; boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0); boundsInScreen: Rect(28, 112 - 28, 112); packageName: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox; className: android.view.View; text: null; error: null; maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: null; viewIdResName: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:id/dummy_focus_view; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: true; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: false; longClickable: false; contextClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false; scrollable: false; actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_UNKNOWN - null]
01-16 20:10:38.586 21873-21873/? I/AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper: Skipping invisible child: android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@8003b966; boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 182, 182); boundsInScreen: Rect(0, 84 - 182, 266); packageName: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox; className: android.view.View; text: null; error: null; maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: null; viewIdResName: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:id/focus_indicator; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: false; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: false; longClickable: false; contextClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false; scrollable: false; actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_UNKNOWN - null]
01-16 20:10:38.591 21873-21873/? I/AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper: Skipping invisible child: android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@80028594; boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 42, 42); boundsInScreen: Rect(668, 2053 - 689, 2074); packageName: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox; className: android.widget.ImageView; text: null; error: null; maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: null; viewIdResName: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:id/active; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: false; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: false; longClickable: false; contextClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false; scrollable: false; actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_UNKNOWN - null]
01-16 20:10:38.592 21873-21873/? I/AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper: Skipping invisible child: android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@800290d7; boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 42, 42); boundsInScreen: Rect(699, 2042 - 741, 2084); packageName: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox; className: android.widget.ImageView; text: null; error: null; maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: null; viewIdResName: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:id/inactive; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: false; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: false; longClickable: false; contextClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false; scrollable: false; actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_UNKNOWN - null]
01-16 20:10:38.592 21873-21873/? I/AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper: Skipping invisible child: android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@80029498; boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 42, 42); boundsInScreen: Rect(752, 2053 - 773, 2074); packageName: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox; className: android.widget.ImageView; text: null; error: null; maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: null; viewIdResName: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:id/active; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: false; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: false; longClickable: false; contextClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false; scrollable: false; actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_UNKNOWN - null]
01-16 20:10:38.593 21873-21873/? I/AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper: Skipping invisible child: android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@8002d469; boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 324, 350); boundsInScreen: Rect(1172, 2126 - 1440, 2392); packageName: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox; className: android.view.View; text: null; error: null; maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: null; viewIdResName: null; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: false; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: false; longClickable: false; contextClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false; scrollable: false; actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_UNKNOWN - null]
01-16 20:10:38.596 21873-21873/? W/AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper: Fetch time: 111ms
```

so if you read the logcat you will find that the tools start a new process [com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-mr1-release/core/java/com/android/internal/os/RuntimeInit.java) then this process calls [com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/jb-dev/uiautomator/cmds/uiautomator/src/com/android/commands/uiautomator/Launcher.java) with some `args` (see the source code of **Launcher** in the main method ) after that the launcher run a specified commande that dump the views from the Launcher view (see logcat).

I hope that's help you but need to more details and researches :)